# Unable to fix logo cropped out to the left

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with the logo. As you can see from the gif, half of it is missing. I am using bootstrap grid system to separate the sidebar and the background slider. I can solve it by using margin but it ruins the responsiveness. Please check this gif I made. https://media.giphy.com/media/KDbPJYlxoGN6tPEcJn/giphy.gif.

This is the code I have been using:

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
      <div class="nav-sidebar">
        <div id="logo">
          <div class="logo">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/RQGBXjK/logo.png">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-xl-10">
      <div class="main-content gradient">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-smoothing: antialiased;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    background: transparent;
}


.container{
    background: transparent;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.nav-sidebar {
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: grey;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(0,0,0,1),rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),url(https://i.ibb.co/1TBvfyP/1.jpg);
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.9), 
                0px 10px 15px 5px #000;
    z-index: 9999;
}

#logo {
    height:130px;
    width:100%;
}


.nav-sidebar #logo .logo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo img{
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 10px 1px #000);
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 10px 2px #000);
}

.main-content{
    height: 100vh;
    background: black;
}


.gradient {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.9),rgba(0,0,0,0.9)),url(https://i.ibb.co/8KSjNdL/gradient.png);
    background-blend-mode: overlay;
    width:100%;
    z-index:9999;
}

.main-content{
    background-position: top 50px center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

For full code please check this codepen: https://codepen.io/zakero/pen/JjjjZMz The logo issue seems to be working in codepen but in my browser its as it is shown in the gif.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/mtr5ky6n/6/

about the logo, it seems like it's affected by .row 's margin-left:-15px

I've added `nopadding` class

Comment: Hey, padding didn't work for me, but then I changed the margin for .row and it worked. Thanks for pointing it out.